# Keyboard is not showing in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, theos

I successfully compiled this tweak using theos, and it shows the UIWebView inside the ViewController, but I can not get the keyboard to show at all when I press any textfield inside the webview, what am I doing wrong?

I have tried the [webView.window makeKeyAndVisible]; [webView canBecomeFirstResponder]; methods but no luck.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface myViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> 
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView; 
@end

%hook myViewController
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    %orig;

        UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 342)];
        [webView setDelegate:self];
        NSString *urlAddress = @"https://www.google.com/";
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
        NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
        webView.scalesPageToFit=YES;
        webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [webView.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        [webView canBecomeFirstResponder];
        [self.view addSubview:webView];

%end
```

Comment: Are you using the Simulator? If so, check that you don't have the hardware keyboard selected (Hardware -> Keyboard -> Connect Hardware Keyboard). If so, the iOS keyboard won't appear and you'll only be able to use your physical keyboard to type. You can use Cmd+K to force-show the iOS keyboard.

Comment: I am using theos to compile this tweak